# Laravel 5 How to populate same view multiple times with different data and cycle between pages

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am quite new to Laravel and I'm trying to build a small application that uses nested views (something like shown below)

[image]

To explain, I have an array of `$categories` which can vary in quantity. Each `$category` contains a different number of `$questions`. I want to create a page of `$questions` for each `$category` using the same view (so each `$category` on a new page).

I want to start with a summary page and be able to cycle Next and Back from each page (except for the first and last pages).

I have created my controller that currently returns me `$categories` and `$questions` and I have fed them into a view. I just don't know how to split them up by `$category` and cycle through the same view.

**Updated**

For my data I have a categories table that has the following structure:

```
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | application_id | sort_order_id   | name            | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |              1 |               1 | Host            | 2017-11-22 06:36:03 | 2017-11-22 06:36:03 |
|  2 |              1 |               4 | Pricing         | 2017-11-22 06:37:37 | 2017-11-22 06:48:14 |
|  3 |              1 |               2 | Security        | 2017-11-22 06:37:59 | 2017-11-22 06:37:59 |
|  4 |              1 |               3 | Software        | 2017-11-22 06:38:40 | 2017-11-22 06:47:51 |
|  5 |              1 |               5 | Hardware        | 2017-11-22 06:42:18 | 2017-11-22 06:45:52 |
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I also have a questions table that has the following structure:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | category_id | sort_order_id   | description        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 |               1 | Question 1         | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 |
|  2 |           1 |               2 | Question 2         | 2017-11-23 02:07:04 | 2017-11-23 02:15:08 |
|  3 |           1 |               3 | Question 3         | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 |
|  4 |           2 |               1 | Question 1         | 2017-11-23 02:17:45 | 2017-11-23 02:17:45 |
|  5 |           2 |               2 | Question 2         | 2017-11-23 02:18:10 | 2017-11-23 02:18:26 |
|  1 |           3 |               1 | Question 1         | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 |
|  2 |           3 |               2 | Question 2         | 2017-11-23 02:07:04 | 2017-11-23 02:15:08 |
|  3 |           3 |               3 | Question 3         | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 |
|  1 |           3 |               4 | Question 4         | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 | 2017-11-23 02:06:54 |
|  2 |           4 |               1 | Question 1         | 2017-11-23 02:07:04 | 2017-11-23 02:15:08 |
|  3 |           4 |               2 | Question 2         | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 |
|  3 |           5 |               1 | Question 1         | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 | 2017-11-23 02:16:36 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The questions link to the category table by the `category_id`. The categories should appear in order of `sort_order_id`. The questions for each `category_id` should appear on its own page.

So, navigation of questions would take the form of (using the above sample data):

Summary<->Host<->Security<->Software<->Pricing<->Hardware<->Results

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: Also this sounds more like you want pagination and routes with category and/or question ids as paramters. Can you clarify or confirm?

Comment: I have used child views: `$view = \View::make( 'tests.edit' )->nest( 'child', 'tests.summary', ['Tests' => $tests] );` Is that the wrong approach? I do use sub views on my partial forms.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to create a page of questions for each category`? Do you mean a distinct, server rendered page, with it's own URL? Or more like a tab for each, all on one page?

Comment: Sorry yes. I might have 5 categories each with 5 questions. I want to show the questions for each category on it's own page but not with a URL route. So when you click Next or Back, it's showing the same page but with different questions. So maybe more like a tab for each, all on the one page.